# Is it possible automate to changing all colors in an image to random colors?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, data-augmentation, image-augmentation

[image]

I'm trying to come up with a new image augmentation that changes colors like above automatically, but to everything not just the flower. The above is a photoshop example but I'd like to automatically switch all colors in the image to a different random color. Is this possible to create a function for this? There are augmentations like random convolution and random jitter, but those aren't quite what I want. I'd like to keep the saturations and values the same just change the color.

Comment: Maybe convert to HSV save and change hue?

Comment: @jkr like scale hue? What were you thinking? I was hoping that images could go up and down on the hue scale. Like yellow could go up one sample of this augmentation and down the next.

Comment: Some continuous transformation on the hue channel, but that wont be completely random.

Comment: note on the answer given below, 1 hour ago: it'll ruin the picture. before upvoting answers, _try_ them.

Comment: @Gooby - i mean something like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67452492/5666087

Comment: to *rotate* the hues: just convert to HSV, add some to the hue channel (but not too much or else you'll overflow the uint8! or calculate with uint16 instead), take modulo 180 so it's a "valid" hue again (opencv maps them onto 0..180, not 0..360, because 360 doesn't fit into uint8), then convert back to BGR/RGB. -- *rotating* hues is a subset of possible transformations. you could map hues in other ways too... say, invert (`180-hue`) or jumble them entirely, but if you do that, make sure they're still continuous

Comment: to keep the background green, and only affect the flower, you'd have to first get a mask for the flower. then you can mess with its hues however you like, without affecting the background. that should be easy, if the flower is colored distinctly from its background.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a random 0 to 255 shift to each channel in BGR and take modulo 256.

In python it would look like:

```py
shift = numpy.random.randint(256, size=(1,1,3))
color_shifted_img = img + shift
color_shifted_img = numpy.mod(color_shifted_img, 256)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I've added a sample output for your code... you didn't run your code. why did you not predict this outcome? this code will just ruin the picture. *also*, it's missing a cast. your `color_shifted_img` is of type `int32`...

Comment: as far as I can tell from your picture, it changed the color to a random color, so it worked as I expected given your description of the problem

Comment: if you don't already see the rgb values wrapping around, making brightness discontinuous as well, I can't help you see that.